# RAID1 drive vanished, but could be re-added after reboot. Should I be worried?

Tags: mdadm, raid1, smart, drive-failure

I am running Debian 12 with an MD RAID1 array (2 drives) for my personal data (no system files on array).

Today I got a mail from mdadm about a DegradedArray event, during a time where my drives are typically not used:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on hostname

A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc[0]
      976630464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

`/var/log/syslog` did not contain anything relevant, but `dmesg` showed:

```
[652897.364496] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen
[652897.364512] ata2: SError: { CommWake }
[652897.364520] ata2.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[652897.364525] ata2.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 15
                         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[652897.364541] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[652897.364549] ata2: hard resetting link
[652902.720479] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652907.364975] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[652907.364988] ata2: hard resetting link
[652912.716814] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652917.365220] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[652917.365233] ata2: hard resetting link
[652922.724814] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652952.365391] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[652952.365406] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[652952.365409] ata2: hard resetting link
[652957.420814] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652957.580941] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652957.580966] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[652962.596788] ata2.00: qc timeout after 5000 msecs (cmd 0xec)
[652962.596807] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[652962.596811] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[652962.596824] ata2: hard resetting link
[652967.956818] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652972.597225] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[652972.597239] ata2: hard resetting link
[652977.188682] INFO: task md0_raid1:242 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[652977.188696]       Not tainted 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.52-1
[652977.188703] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[652977.188708] task:md0_raid1       state:D stack:0     pid:242   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[652977.188716] Call Trace:
[652977.188719]  <TASK>
[652977.188724]  __schedule+0x351/0xa20
[652977.188736]  schedule+0x5d/0xe0
[652977.188745]  md_super_wait+0x9e/0xd0 [md_mod]
[652977.188770]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[652977.188777]  write_page+0x2b7/0x3c0 [md_mod]
[652977.188801]  ? md_super_wait+0x23/0xd0 [md_mod]
[652977.188824]  md_update_sb.part.0+0x300/0x7e0 [md_mod]
[652977.188847]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[652977.188868]  md_check_recovery+0x15a/0x5b0 [md_mod]
[652977.188892]  raid1d+0x8a/0x1990 [raid1]
[652977.188903]  ? update_load_avg+0x7e/0x780
[652977.188910]  ? psi_group_change+0x145/0x360
[652977.188915]  ? sched_clock_local+0xe/0x80
[652977.188920]  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0x15/0x30
[652977.188925]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x9b/0x300
[652977.188929]  ? __switch_to+0x106/0x410
[652977.188936]  ? __schedule+0x359/0xa20
[652977.188943]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[652977.188963]  ? preempt_count_add+0x6a/0xa0
[652977.188966]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x23/0x50
[652977.188970]  ? preempt_count_add+0x6a/0xa0
[652977.188975]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[652977.188993]  md_thread+0xaa/0x180 [md_mod]
[652977.189012]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[652977.189017]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[652977.189023]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[652977.189028]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[652977.189036]  </TASK>
[652977.189041] INFO: task jbd2/md0-8:1065 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[652977.189046]       Not tainted 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.52-1
[652977.189051] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[652977.189056] task:jbd2/md0-8      state:D stack:0     pid:1065  ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[652977.189061] Call Trace:
[652977.189062]  <TASK>
[652977.189064]  __schedule+0x351/0xa20
[652977.189071]  schedule+0x5d/0xe0
[652977.189076]  md_write_start+0x198/0x2a0 [md_mod]
[652977.189095]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[652977.189100]  raid1_make_request+0xac/0xbaf [raid1]
[652977.189109]  ? iomap_iter+0x78/0x310
[652977.189116]  ? mempool_alloc+0x85/0x1b0
[652977.189122]  ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x148/0x2e0
[652977.189129]  md_handle_request+0x131/0x1e0 [md_mod]
[652977.189149]  __submit_bio+0x89/0x130
[652977.189154]  submit_bio_noacct_nocheck+0x163/0x370
[652977.189159]  ? submit_bio_noacct+0x79/0x4a0
[652977.189163]  jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0xdb3/0x1a70 [jbd2]
[652977.189187]  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0x15/0x30
[652977.189191]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x9b/0x300
[652977.189194]  ? __switch_to+0x106/0x410
[652977.189202]  kjournald2+0xa9/0x280 [jbd2]
[652977.189222]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[652977.189227]  ? jbd2_fc_wait_bufs+0xa0/0xa0 [jbd2]
[652977.189246]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[652977.189250]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[652977.189256]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[652977.189263]  </TASK>
[652977.948973] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[652982.597296] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[652982.597309] ata2: hard resetting link
[652987.948814] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653017.597291] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653017.597306] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[653017.597309] ata2: hard resetting link
[653022.648471] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653022.808780] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653022.808797] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[653032.996794] ata2.00: qc timeout after 10000 msecs (cmd 0xec)
[653032.996813] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[653032.996817] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[653032.996832] ata2: hard resetting link
[653038.348823] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653042.996967] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653042.996982] ata2: hard resetting link
[653048.348821] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653052.996756] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653052.996770] ata2: hard resetting link
[653058.348811] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653087.997129] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653087.997145] ata2: hard resetting link
[653093.057056] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653093.216467] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653093.216484] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[653098.020894] INFO: task kcompactd0:71 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[653098.020910]       Not tainted 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.52-1
[653098.020918] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[653098.020923] task:kcompactd0      state:D stack:0     pid:71    ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[653098.020932] Call Trace:
[653098.020935]  <TASK>
[653098.020940]  __schedule+0x351/0xa20
[653098.020952]  ? bit_wait+0x60/0x60
[653098.020959]  schedule+0x5d/0xe0
[653098.020965]  io_schedule+0x42/0x70
[653098.020971]  bit_wait_io+0xd/0x60
[653098.020977]  __wait_on_bit_lock+0x5f/0xa0
[653098.020984]  out_of_line_wait_on_bit_lock+0x91/0xb0
[653098.020991]  ? sugov_init+0x350/0x350
[653098.020997]  __buffer_migrate_folio+0xb8/0x270
[653098.021006]  move_to_new_folio+0x56/0x150
[653098.021013]  migrate_pages+0xc51/0x1480
[653098.021019]  ? isolate_freepages_block+0x410/0x410
[653098.021027]  ? release_freepages+0xc0/0xc0
[653098.021034]  ? do_pages_stat+0x360/0x360
[653098.021041]  compact_zone+0x97e/0xdb0
[653098.021048]  ? sched_clock_local+0xe/0x80
[653098.021053]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x9b/0x300
[653098.021059]  proactive_compact_node+0x87/0xc0
[653098.021069]  kcompactd+0x34c/0x420
[653098.021075]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[653098.021080]  ? kcompactd_do_work+0x2a0/0x2a0
[653098.021086]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[653098.021092]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[653098.021098]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[653098.021107]  </TASK>
[653098.021117] INFO: task md0_raid1:242 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
[653098.021124]       Not tainted 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.52-1
[653098.021129] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[653098.021134] task:md0_raid1       state:D stack:0     pid:242   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[653098.021139] Call Trace:
[653098.021141]  <TASK>
[653098.021143]  __schedule+0x351/0xa20
[653098.021150]  schedule+0x5d/0xe0
[653098.021157]  md_super_wait+0x9e/0xd0 [md_mod]
[653098.021179]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[653098.021184]  write_page+0x2b7/0x3c0 [md_mod]
[653098.021205]  ? md_super_wait+0x23/0xd0 [md_mod]
[653098.021225]  md_update_sb.part.0+0x300/0x7e0 [md_mod]
[653098.021246]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[653098.021265]  md_check_recovery+0x15a/0x5b0 [md_mod]
[653098.021286]  raid1d+0x8a/0x1990 [raid1]
[653098.021296]  ? update_load_avg+0x7e/0x780
[653098.021301]  ? psi_group_change+0x145/0x360
[653098.021305]  ? sched_clock_local+0xe/0x80
[653098.021310]  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0x15/0x30
[653098.021314]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x9b/0x300
[653098.021318]  ? __switch_to+0x106/0x410
[653098.021324]  ? __schedule+0x359/0xa20
[653098.021330]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[653098.021349]  ? preempt_count_add+0x6a/0xa0
[653098.021352]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x23/0x50
[653098.021356]  ? preempt_count_add+0x6a/0xa0
[653098.021360]  ? unregister_md_personality+0x70/0x70 [md_mod]
[653098.021379]  md_thread+0xaa/0x180 [md_mod]
[653098.021398]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[653098.021403]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[653098.021407]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[653098.021412]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[653098.021420]  </TASK>
[653098.021424] INFO: task jbd2/md0-8:1065 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
[653098.021430]       Not tainted 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.52-1
[653098.021435] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[653098.021440] task:jbd2/md0-8      state:D stack:0     pid:1065  ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[653098.021445] Call Trace:
[653098.021446]  <TASK>
[653098.021449]  __schedule+0x351/0xa20
[653098.021455]  schedule+0x5d/0xe0
[653098.021460]  md_write_start+0x198/0x2a0 [md_mod]
[653098.021479]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[653098.021484]  raid1_make_request+0xac/0xbaf [raid1]
[653098.021493]  ? iomap_iter+0x78/0x310
[653098.021500]  ? mempool_alloc+0x85/0x1b0
[653098.021505]  ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x148/0x2e0
[653098.021511]  md_handle_request+0x131/0x1e0 [md_mod]
[653098.021531]  __submit_bio+0x89/0x130
[653098.021536]  submit_bio_noacct_nocheck+0x163/0x370
[653098.021541]  ? submit_bio_noacct+0x79/0x4a0
[653098.021545]  jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0xdb3/0x1a70 [jbd2]
[653098.021569]  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0x15/0x30
[653098.021573]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x9b/0x300
[653098.021577]  ? __switch_to+0x106/0x410
[653098.021584]  kjournald2+0xa9/0x280 [jbd2]
[653098.021604]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[653098.021609]  ? jbd2_fc_wait_bufs+0xa0/0xa0 [jbd2]
[653098.021628]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[653098.021633]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[653098.021638]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[653098.021645]  </TASK>
[653124.644468] ata2.00: qc timeout after 30000 msecs (cmd 0xec)
[653124.644485] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[653124.644493] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[653124.644498] ata2.00: disable device
[653130.000802] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653134.645444] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653140.000802] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653144.644791] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653149.996821] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653179.644808] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653184.696807] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653184.856889] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653184.856909] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[653184.856943] ata2: EH complete
[653184.856995] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=348s
[653184.857003] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[653184.857013] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[653184.857028] md: super_written gets error=-5
[653184.857036] md/raid1:md0: Disk failure on sdb, disabling device.
                md/raid1:md0: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
[653185.608789] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653194.896744] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653200.648480] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653204.896652] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653210.648810] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653239.896810] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653239.896826] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[653244.928818] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653245.088464] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653245.088484] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[653245.088491] ata2: link online but 1 devices misclassified, device detection might fail
[653245.088528] ata2.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
[653245.152505] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[653245.832890] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653255.116619] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653260.868780] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653265.116809] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653270.868804] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653300.116654] ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
[653300.116670] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[653305.148810] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653305.308456] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[653305.308473] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[653305.308480] ata2: link online but 1 devices misclassified, device detection might fail
[653305.312951] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[653305.312958] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[653305.312979] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[867105.099901] md: data-check of RAID array md0
[867105.101757] md: md0: data-check done.
```

I found out that the drive suddenly vanished, i.e. `lsblk` and `blkid` did not list the drive anymore, as if it was not physically installed.

I did a backup and after a reboot the drive was listed again and could be added using `sudo mdadm --re-add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd`. After that, everything looked normal again. E.g. `dmesg` showed:

```
[ 3519.982027] md: recovery of RAID array md0
[ 3575.888503] md: md0: recovery done.
```

`sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Aug  6 17:58:09 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Oct  1 12:02:14 2023
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : nas:0  (local to host nas)
              UUID : 6d6bb2a5:d42475de:ce618a52:28bd98bb
            Events : 3719

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
```

`sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd`:

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.0-12-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Skyhawk
Device Model:     ST1000VX005-2EZ102
Serial Number:    Z9CB4EPK
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0c45a18ab
Firmware Version: CV11
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5900 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct  1 11:54:51 2023 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 130) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x10bb) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   063   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       153886026
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       494
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   069   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       9994348
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       9604h+00m+00.000s
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       37
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   062   040    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 28/35)
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       880
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   020   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 20 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   003   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       153886026
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I find this occurrence strange. My question now is: Should I replace the drive or wait until one actually reports S.M.A.R.T. errors?

Comment: It's a seven year old one TB hard drive. Hardware failure rate increases after five years.

Comment: @GregAskew it reports 9604h = 400 days of running, not even close to 7 years

Comment: the more interesting questions is, how old are the drives and at this point I would believe that Greg told it correctly

Comment: Skyhawk drive has five years warranty. The Seagate warranty lookup page shows warranty expired March 21, 2023...

Comment: 5 years start from the date of purchase, if you still have the proof of purchase. If you don't have it, yes, Seagate warranty lookup date applies. But my point was, the mentioned increased failure rate is due to the mechanical wear, and in this case the drive's mechanics isn't worn that much. There could be other problems, like corrosion, electrolytic condensers failing and so on, but the "increased failure rate after 5 years" isn't about that.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even know they were that old. It was a private purchase about 2 years ago, so no warranty unfortunately.
btw, no problems since the reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* the problem is `powertop --autotune`, which is run at server boot. This can cause the drive to disappear, for which I unfortunately only have anectodal evidence and [this german forum post](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/129612-3-missing-disks-nach-powertop/) as a hint.

Btw, it was the first time the drive was in standby for 2 days straight.